# Does location actually matter?

Tags: animal-crossing-happy-home-designer

When you get a new client, you need to pick the location for their house. The game tells you to select one that suits their needs. Does it matter? Does the season you pick matter? Or is it just cosmetic?

Answer (score 1):

No, the location you pick doesn't really matter. The client will accept any location that's available on the map, regardless of season.